# Can an investigator ever have more than 1 of a kind of condition

Tags: eldritch-horror

The Growing Madness rumor says

> the lead investigator gains a madness condition then discards 1
>   eldritch token from this card for each madness condition he has

I would have expected the card to simply say

> the lead investigator gains a madness condition. Then, discard 1 eldritch token from this card.

The wording makes it seem like there are situations where one might have to discard more than 1 token. Is this possible considering the  quick reference says, under Conditions:

> An investigator cannot have multiple copies of the same condition. If he would gain a condition he already has a copy of, he does not gain another copy of that condition.

Comment: Isn't there more than one kind of madness condition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jefromi has pointed out that there is more than one Madness condition, such as Paranoia, Amnesia, and Hallucinations. Consequently, an investigator can have more than one madness condition, as long as they are not the same. I hadn't realized madness was a category of condition.